# Pivot columns based on aggregated values

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this, it contains variables: ptid, time, type num and volume.

```
structure(list(ptid = c("30000", "30000", "30000", "30000", "30000", 
"30001", "30002", "30002", "30002", "30003", "30003", "30003", 
"30004", "30004", "30004", "30005", "30005", "30005", "30006", 
"30006", "30006", "30007", "30007", "30007", "30007", "30008", 
"30008", "30008", "30008", "30008"), num = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), levels = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "factor"), type = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("0", 
"1", "2"), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), volume = c(694L, 745L, 415L, 201L, 446L, 
589L, 99L, 887L, 266L, 261L, 188L, 391L, 240L, 221L, 578L, 296L, 
596L, 204L, 703L, 113L, 370L, 922L, 419L, 168L, 879L, 856L, 800L, 
736L, 386L, 912L)), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

In original/provided dataset: there are four variables: **ptid** is patientID; **num** is how many times you got the flu shot; **type** is flu shot type (valid values are 0,1,3); **volume** is continues variable which is the volume of flu shot, **time** has values 0 and 1, which means that 0=before RCT, 1=After RCT.

Suppose now, I need to create a wider table based on the time, num, and type. What I need is that under each participant:

1)**totalvol**: which counts the total volume by each ptid no matter what type of flu shot they got.
Besides,three vars: **voltype0, voltype1, voltype2**: those count before and after time (eg. voltyp0 =sum (time=1+time=0)group by ptied and type).

2)type indicator: including **totalyn**=As long as the patient get any type of shot, its value is 1, else is 0.
**type1yn,type2yn,type3yn**:  represent the whether the patient got the each type of flu shot. Say, if the patient got the flu shot type 1 and not for others, then the type1yn=1, type2yn=0,type3yn=0.

The desired output should be like this:

[image]

I tried to write the code like this (the variable name may be different as I used as example above, but the purpose and whole idea is the same):

```
wide_data <-dfq2 %>%
  mutate(num=as.numeric(num))%>%
  group_by(ptid,type)%>%
        mutate(subvol=sum(volume)) %>%
  mutate(subnum=max(num), 
         type_copy=type, 
         type_copy3=type)%>%
    mutate(totbol0yn=factor(ifelse(type==0, 1, 0)),
         totbol1yn=factor(ifelse(type==1, 1, 0)),
         totbol2yn=factor(ifelse(type==3, 1, 0)), 
         totbolusyn=factor(ifelse(is.na(type), 0, 1))) %>%
  ungroup%>%
  group_by(ptid)%>%
         mutate(totbolusvol=sum(volume))%>%
  ungroup%>%
  pivot_wider(
            names_from ="type",
            names_prefix = "tolvol",
            names_sep = "_",
            values_from = "subvol")%>%
  pivot_wider(
            names_from = "type_copy3",
            names_prefix = "tolnum",
            names_sep = "_",
            values_from = "subnum")
```

What I tried to do is first I want to calculate the values for each dervied variables aforementioned. Then use piovt_wider to reshape dataset. However, my code dose not work. It either creates a list of value after pivot_wider (say when I use type and type_copy to pivot_wider twice to get each patient row) or cannot use var "type" (that is why I created type_copy in the code) to do second pivot_wider.

So my question is how to get all information based on the participant as one row?

Thanks a lot for help~~!

Comment: FYI, I've made two suggested edits to your question so far (the first was undone on your recent update, np), please make sure that the footnote `[1]` with the URL to the image must have an empty line before and after it. Regardless of needed-rep to immediately show images (in the interim needing somebody like me to make it visible for you), it takes more edits/fixes to work around that. Please keep that empty space, the interface should be putting it in there to begin with.

Comment: Noticing that this question doesn't have answers yet... I'd suggest trying to make your example more **minimal**. I'm much more likely to work on a question with 10-20 rows where I can easily see what's going on, than an example with almost 600 rows. Can you illustrate your problem with a smaller sample data set?

Comment: Most people on the site generally agree that the smallest example that illustrates the problem is best. It is, of course, possible to make an example so small that it no longer illustrates the problem, or to choose it poorly so it doesn't make a good illustration (I think that's what would happen here with a random sample). This is [described in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).